# Why is there no unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for Poisson Distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, poisson-distribution

> Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is an iid random sample from a Poisson distribution with mean $\theta$. I would like to prove that there exists no unbiased estimator of $\frac{1}{\theta}$.

To do so, I will let $\bar\theta(X)$ be an estimator of $\frac{1}{\theta}$. Then, I'd like to equate the expectation of $\bar\theta(X)$ and $\frac{1}{\theta}$
$$E\left[\bar\theta(X)\right] = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\bar\theta(x)P(X=x)$$

Now, my problem is that I don't know what to do next. I can write the probability $P(X=x)$ out but how do I continue from there? I have no information of $\bar\theta$ which is inside the sum. Any ideas?

Comment: If $E_\theta(\bar\theta(X_1,\ldots,X_n))=1/\theta$ for every $\theta>0$, then, when $\theta\to0$, $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\to(0,\ldots,0)$ in distribution hence $E_\theta(\bar\theta(X_1,\ldots,X_n))\to\bar\theta(0,\ldots,0)$ while the RHS is unbounded.

Comment: what is a RHS? Also what is $\bar\theta(0,...,0)$?

Comment: why is $\bar\theta(0,...,0)$ bounded?

Comment: Well, $\bar\theta(0,\ldots,0)$ is *a number*.

Comment: You are confusing $X$. The $X$ in $\bar{\theta}(X)$ is the vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, so your expression about $E[\bar{\theta}(X)]$ is not correct.